# Can the image/jpeg library in Go support JPEG progressive format

Tags: google-app-engine, go

The Go runtime (the version that is in google appengine) package image/jpeg returns "unsupported JPEG feature: progressive mode" when trying to Decode a JPEG that uses progressive format. Is this an error on my part? Or is this type of JPEG not yet decodable in Go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be included in the upcoming Go 1.1 release.

[Revision: 51f26e36ba98](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/detail?r=51f26e36ba987e7d03c8feb57850b065be324c5b): image/jpeg: decode progressive JPEGs.